# What's the technical term for additional material at the start and end of a take?

Tags: editing, terminology, footage

When shooting footage, it's good practice to start a little earlier and end a little later than the actual action. That way, you get more freedom during editing. The same holds true for animated sequences or visual effects.

I'm sure there must be a technical term for that additional time at the start and end of a clip. I'd like to say 'this clip requires 5 frames *[additional material at the start]* and 10 frames *[additional material at the end]*'.

What's the term I'm missing? Googling didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't cite any authority, but the term I've used and heard most often is ***handles***. It's not just used for live shots, but refers to any trimmable material that allows for transition points to be adjusted, etc. In your example I'd say "this clip requires 10-frame handles".

Answer (score 1):

I have heard the term `padding` but don't know if it's a standardized term

From [The Art of The Edit](http://www.videomaker.com/article/f5/1691-the-art-of-the-edit):

> To allow time for a good transition, instruct your talent to fix a
>   gaze on the camera for two seconds before and several seconds after a
>   narration. A quick, sideways glance for approval, a swallow or a lick
>   of the lips before or after speaking may be difficult to edit out.

May be confused with pre-roll

> Be sure to allow for pre-roll. When you switch a camera from the stop
>   mode to record, it rolls back several seconds before it achieves
>   "speed" and begins taping. Allow five seconds, 10 to be safe, before
>   cuing the talent to begin speaking or executing your shot.